# How to make a maven build fail if source code contains a keyword / regex

Tags: maven

### Question

How to make a maven build fail if source code contains a keyword / regex?

### Bonus

- Be able to specify which path to check
- <del>Be able to specify which "kind" of path to check :</del>

  - <del>"I want to be sure that KEYWORD is not contained in 'main' resources. I don't care about 'test'"</del>
  - <del>"I want to be sure that KEYWORD is not contained in 'test' resources. I don't care about 'main'"</del>
  - ...
- Be able to specify on which phase to execute the test (Eg. before compilation)

### Solution

(Based on current answers 2013-09-26)

Best solution yet seems to be @BaptisteMathus [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19004735/233906) that fully integrates with maven and is platform independant.

In my use case, @GregWhitaker [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18129556/233906) is the good one because it's cheaper to implement as *I don't care about platform independency* (<= the required command is availiable on all my hosts). 
The code sample below is a solution based on this answer, it forbids usage of "FIXME" or "Auto-generated method stub" but is assuming that `egrep` is availiable.

Please see also @MarkOConnor [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18134220/233906) that is cleaner in "SONAR enabled" project

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>egrep</executable>
                        <successCodes>
                            <successCode>1</successCode>
                        </successCodes>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-rqm</argument>
                            <argument>1</argument>
                            <!-- Forbidden Keywords -->
                            <argument>FIXME|Auto-generated method stub</argument>
                            <!-- search path -->
                            <argument>src/main</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering why this kind of rule might be useful, here is a good example: due to a project team made up of people who have different mother tongues, we have classes and methods that use the spellings Organisation and Organization. We even have an enum called OrganisationType and another enum called OrganizationType. Being able to set a rule at the beginning of the project would have saved us a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to SonarQube to do that is not a bad idea.

Anyway, if someone wants to use a maven-only solution, then the right way would then be by using a plugin dedicated to "enforce" things with maven builds. Using exec-maven-plugin is not that standard and certainly too much platform-dependent.

This plugin is logically named [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) and [writing a custom enforcer rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) is actually very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a small program to run these checks and then execute it via the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).  If you find the keyword in the main resources then just return a non-zero return code which will cause the plugin to fail the build.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I thought about it too and especially about "`grep`ing" the value. What this lacks is a way to determine in which directories the source code is located : I have a few projects with non-standard layout (and they do works fine with standard maven plugins)

Comment: @Cerber - You should be able to pass the source code directories in as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [taglist-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/taglist-maven-plugin/) is exactly what you want.

Comment: I didn't know about this plugin.  Thanks for mentioning it.  Looking at the usage though I don't see how to make it fail the build.  How would you go about getting it to fail the build if you don't like what is in the generated report?

Comment: Now that you mention that, it seems like it's only reporting. But it shouldn't be too hard to add a goal which fails the build based on the result.

Comment: That's the most important part in fact : failing! / preventing the build to occur. I thought to use this plugin bug couldn't find a way to make it fail (except forking the project, going deep in the source code and creating a brand new plugin that only I will use ... I'd rather find an official plugin ;) ) Anyway thanks for looking at this question Robert.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar has a [taglist](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Taglist+Plugin) plugin, which allows you to search for strings in your comment blocks and specify the severity handling. I'm assuming that is what you're looking for... Parsing the source code itself might require a custom rule for a tool like checkstyle, I haven't tried this approach but it's [documented on the Sonar site](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules).

This can be coupled with the [build breaker](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin) plugin, which fails your build when an alert criteria is breached in your project's [quality profile](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles).

Comment: Very nice ! I didn't knew about "build breaker". I think I'll use your solution as a more advanced approach to @GregWhitaker solution. On some project I was already using a custom sonar rule to create a blocker and then did a manual review. But I'm very keen on getting things done automatically :) Unfortunatly the project that triggered this question is not monitored by sonar ...