# For security purposes, is there a way to make code fail if it's written a certain way?

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I'm using JPA and Maven in a project.  It's possible, but semantically wrong to write code that does this:

```
entityManager.find(EntityWithRestrictedData.class, key);
```

or

```
entityManager.findAll(EntityWithRestrictedData.class);
```

The project already has code that should be used instead:

```
getEntityWithRestrictedDataONLYIfYouHaveAccess(key, user);
```

Is there any way to have the build fail if someone uses the entity manager to find restricted data directly?

Keep in mind that in my project there are other perfectly valid reasons to use `find` and `findAll`, just not with the `EntityWithRestrictedData`.

EDIT: This question may be a duplicate of this, [How to make a maven build fail if source code contains a keyword / regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129106/how-to-make-a-maven-build-fail-if-source-code-contains-a-keyword-regex)

Comment: Put EntityWithRestrictedData in a protected package, make its constructor protected and wrap it around a Builder or Factory.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos I have a feeling JPA will throw a fit with that

Comment: Actually, it may be ok: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html

Comment: I'm not sure about via Maven, but something like a custom FindBugs or Sonar rule might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not even sure how you'd go about *defining* what a forbidden call looks like. This is the sort of thing where AOP is generally preferable, and/or you shouldn't be using the `EntityManager` directly in the code that's outside the security perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach that Alexandre suggests in his comment is going to be the right way to do it, reasoning by process of elimination. Here's my thinking.

The candidate approaches: (1) static analysis, (2) compile-time enforcement, (3) runtime enforcement. Of the three I think only (2) is feasible here.

**Static analysis:** Static analysis doesn't work, because one can always do things like

```
ReflectionUtils.invoke(
        myEM,
        myFindAllMethod,
        Class.forName("x.y.EntityWithRestrictedDat" + "apple".substring(0, 1)));
```

**Runtime enforcement:** Also, runtime enforcement doesn't seem feasible either, because there would have to be a unit test that both exercised the offending code and used an appropriate call-rejecting mock. I don't think you can force those things.

**Compile-time enforcement:** So that leaves compile-time enforcement. [The compiler performs various security checks](http://www.webbasedprogramming.com/JAVA-Developers-Guide/ch39.htm#CompilerSecurityFeatures), but (I think) the only relevant one here is visibility checking. So you have to make the called class, the called method, or the passed class unavailable for general use. You don't control `EntityManager` or `findAll()` visibility. So the only thing left is to make `EntityWithRestrictedData` unavailable in the way Alexandre suggests. Force interactions with this entity to occur behind a service.

This is a case where I'd be very excited to hear about having overlooked a possibility.

Comment: The `ReflectionUtils` example is true, but such an edge case I don't mind it being possible.

Comment: There are more benign cases that will still be hard to catch with static analysis, like entityManager.findAll(requestedClass). Having said that you can certainly use static analysis to flag entityManager.findAll(EntityWithRestrictedData.class), which may be good enough for your purposes.